# Spring PathVariable length limit

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, spring-mvc

First I have server Jetty, and Spring there.
I use AngularJS on client side. And Spring - post/get methods on server side.
I'm trying send some "parameter" with length about 1000 characters - just simple text. Angular showing normal - all 1000 characters. But when I catching in POST method my request - I have just first 255 characters. But I need see all 1000 characters. A tried search anything about PathVariable length, or request max size and etc. But ca't find anything.
May be anybody tell what's happening?
So, I have Controller.java with some method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/create_script/{listId}/{body}", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "text/json;charset=UTF-8")
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
@ResponseBody
public String createScript(@PathVariable(value = "listId") String listId, @PathVariable(value = "body") String body) {
...
}
```

So, in result I have String body with length just 255 characters(

I have: jetty.version: 9.2.5.v20141112;
spring.version: 4.1.4.RELEASE

Comment: Depending on the browser the URL you can use is limited to a certain amount of chars. Don't use the URL for that use the form or request body for large data parts not the URL.

Comment: I have Firefox. In Firefox about 2 Mb as I khow...but in method have just 255..

Comment: Is there a `.` in the `body`? Also I strongly suggest using the request body instead of the URL for large content as that is what it is intended for.

Comment: public String createScript(@PathVariable(value = "listId") String listId, @RequestBody String json)

Comment: I used this. It's working. Thanks.!!! :)